# How do I safely embed a youtube video into a Chrome extension without violating Content Security Policy?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I've been searching around for answers on this issues for a while now but couldn't get any of the provided solutions to work.

Here's the youtube code I'm trying to embed: 
http://jsfiddle.net/BFDKS/1204/

The video iframe is added to index.html and within app.js I call:

```
    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var player;

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady() {
        player.playVideo();
        // Mute!
        player.mute();
    }
```

The problem is I receive a CSR error in the console
[image]

This leads me to my manifest.json file:

```
{
"name": "",
"manifest_version": 2,
"version": "0.0.6",
"icons": {
  "16": "icon-16.png",
  "48": "icon-48.png",
  "128": "icon-128.png"
},
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com/; https://www.youtube.com/*; object-src 'self'",
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "*://*.google-analytics.com/*"
],
"chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "index.html"
},
"description": ""
```

}

That's basically where I'm at now and having trouble making progress. I'm really just trying to embed a autoplaying youtube video that is muted by default with closed captions turned on. Any ideas? Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Same problem when changing to: "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://www.youtube.com/* object-src 'self'; child-src 'self'"

My syntax may still be off though. How does that look?

Comment: Ok I removed google-analytics for now, here's what I have for youtube:     "content_security_policy": "child-src 'self' https://www.youtube.com/", (stackoverflow may not display the https & www. but i have it in there). Still no luck with that approach.

Comment: > "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://www.youtube.com/; object-src 'self'; child-src 'self';"

Results in new errors:
>Refused to frame 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/QjZk7N7RXfA?rel=0&cc_load_policy=1&cc_lang_pref=en&autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "child-src 'self'". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'child-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: And > Refused to load the script 'https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflWkV39n/www-widgetapi.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://www.youtube.com/".

Comment: Your child-src doesn't have the youtube url.

Comment: I'm so confused about the syntax to use here :(

Comment: Just put it inside a webview instead. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tags/webview

Comment: Is app.js a background page or a content script?

Comment: Please add code and errors as **text** ([using code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images do not allow us to copy & paste the code/errors for testing. In addition, an image of your code/error does not permit it to be searched based on the code/error contents.  In general, code/errors in text format >>> code/errors as an image >>> nothing.  Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out, the manifest.json file needed the following:

```
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://www.youtube.com/ https://s.ytimg.com; object-src 'self'; child-src https://www.youtube.com/ https://s.ytimg.com",
```

Thank you for the guidance wOxxOm

Comment: Afaict, the trailing slash is important